# How do I convert the rows of a matrix to columns in Python without NumPy?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am working on a Sudoku Solver in Python, and I need to create functions in it. One of them checks the Sudoku Matrix and returns the number of rows in it that contains a repeating number.

```
def findRepeatsInColumn(matrix):
    numRepeats = 0
    for row in matrix:
        safeChars=['[', ']', '/']
        usedChars=[]
        for char in str(row):
            if char in usedChars and char not in safeChars:
                numRepeats += 1
                break
            else:
                usedChars.append(char)
    return numRepeats
```

If I pass a matrix `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]` to it, it functions fine and gives me the output 3, but for checking all columns for repeated numbers, I need to convert the rows into columns, which means I would need something like: `Input: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
Output: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`
Any thoughts on how I could do this without NumPy?

Comment: Suggestion: use numpy, its optimised

Comment: Suggestion 2: use `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]` instead of `[[111], [222], [333]]`

Comment: @AngusTay I hardly believe it is easy to vectorize the operations you would need to implement for a sudoku solver. Unless one plans on using Numba.

Comment: @Angus, transpose in numpy is easy, but iterations like this are slower.  Conversion to/from arrays is also slow.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to make use of `zip` and `*`:

```
>>> ip = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

>>> print(list(zip(*ip)))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a matrix named `m`

```
transposed = zip(*m)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your input is`numpy.array` you may use the transpose:

```
i = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
print(i.T)
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

---

or you could use:

```
list(map(list, zip(*i)))
```